# Illegal Argument Exception: Illegal base64 character 3a when decoding String value using Base64.getDecode()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, base64, decode

The string value I'm decoding is "ed:1234" but it is throwing an error of IllegalArgumentException. Would greatly appreciate if someone knows why I have this error.

Code:

```
String authInfo = "ed:1234";
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(authInfo);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is the `:` ([ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) decimal 58 or hex 3a) is only valid in one (of several) Base64 encoding schemes, you want [`Base64.getMimeDecoder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getMimeDecoder--). Like,

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(authInfo);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

which outputs (with no other changes)

```
[121, -35, 118, -33]
```