# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, base64

When I get a user from the database I want to add the string which tells the browser "ehy yo this is an image ok? good" to the profile picture field, except that's a byte array type so I have to encode it, add the string, then decode it again, all is good, except it isn't, because when I decode the string to make it a byte array again I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a
```

this is the method:

```
    @GetMapping("/getUser")
    public UserEntity getUser(@RequestHeader("nickname") String nickname) {
        UserEntity user = userDAO.findUserByNickname(nickname);
        user.setPropic(decompressBytes(user.getPropic()));
        String propic = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+ 
                        Base64Utils.encodeToString(user.getPropic());
        //this causes the error
        user.setPropic(Base64Utils.decodeFromString(propic)); 
        return user;
}
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264433/illegal-argument-exception-illegal-base64-character-3a-when-decoding-string-val answer your question?

Comment: your string `propic` is not a base64 string, but a data uri string that contains a base64 string. You would need to cut off the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` part to convert back to byte array

Comment: 3a is the colon `:`. You cannot decode "data:image/jpeg;base64,..." as Base64 because it starts with text.

Comment: ugh fine I'll just add it from the frontend

Answer (score -2):

Whether it's an image or not, if you use base64, please keep the same codec. For example, the decoding of images in apache.common and java.util is different.
Your problem seems to be that the codec uses different tools, please try to start from this aspect.
Haha sure, hope you can provide more code.

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```

and

```
java.util.Base64
```

is different.
You can try it.